# Serve static files from Azure blob container in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-blob-storage

I store static files (js, css and images etc) for web application in an Azure Blob container and want to use those files in application with `app.UseStaticFiles`. Is this possible?

Previously I used `PhysicalFileProvider` to map folder path, but now I want to map one Azure Blob container.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
                       {
                           FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("c:/folder"),
                           RequestPath = new PathString("/cdn"),
                           ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
                       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below references:

- Providing the files in asp.net mvc via Azure Blob Storage may be
  achieved by using the NuGet package
  `Strathweb.AspNetCore.AzureBlobFileProvider`
- Check if you can place your static content in public containers with
  read access.

public class Startup
{
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
Configuration = configuration;
}

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var blobOptions = new AzureBlobOptions
        {
           ConnectionString = "{CONNECTION STRING}",
           DocumentContainer = "{BLOB CONTAINER NAME}"
        }
        
        var azureBlobFileProvider = new AzureBlobFileProvider(blobOptions);
        services.AddSingleton(azureBlobFileProvider);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var blobFileProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<AzureBlobFileProvider>();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = blobFileProvider,
            RequestPath = "/files"
        });

        app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
        {
            FileProvider = blobFileProvider,
            RequestPath = "/files"
        });
    }
}
```

**Reference**: [**GitHub -Strathweb.AspNetCore.AzureBlobFileProvider**](https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.AspNetCore.AzureBlobFileProvider)

See from [Azure .NET Core Web App and Where to Locate Static Files - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1276969/Azure-NET-Core-Web-App-and-Where-to-Locate-Static)

You could also use a combination of the options, using the local static files via the PhysicalFileProvider on Development, and trying to then switch to Blob storage in production .

*Example:*

```
//  static files under wwwroot handled normally
app.UseStaticFiles();

// The path in the url we will manage
var staticFilesPath =
    Configuration.GetSection("StaticFilesPath").Value;

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The local/network folder containing static files we are mapping to
    var staticFilesFolder =
        Configuration.GetSection("StaticFilesFolder").Value;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(staticFilesFolder))
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(staticFilesFolder),
            RequestPath = staticFilesPath
        });
    }
}
else
{
    //  map to blob storage for the path
    var blobFileProvider =
        app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<AzureBlobFileProvider>();
    if (blobFileProvider != null)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = blobFileProvider,
            RequestPath = staticFilesPath
        });
    }
}
```

Please refer [**Azure .NET Core Web App and Where to Locate Static Files – CodeHelper.Net**](http://codehelper.net/asp-net/azure-net-core-web-app-and-where-to-locate-static-files/)